# Copy files from different folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

exists some way, how to copy files from different folders, when I don't know names of it?

Imagine that I have following folders and files

```
C:
  Build
    Tests
      DomainA.UnitTests
        bin
          domainA.dll
        src
          ...
      DomainA.IntegrationTests
        bin
          domainA.dll
        src
          ...
      DomainB.UnitTests
        bin
          domainB.dll
        src
          ...
```

For example in linux I can write command which copy files *domainA.dll* and *domainB.dll*:

```
cp -u Tests/*.UnitTests/bin/*.* Artifacts/Tests/UnitTests
```

and I need to write command/script with same behavior in windows command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a command line, I'd probably use [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), which is basically how you always do everything non-trivial with `cmd`:

```
for /d %d in (.\Tests\*.UnitTests) do (
    pushd %d\bin
    copy *.* ..\..\..\Artifacts\Tests\UnitTests
    popd
)
```

(Remember to use `%%d` in a batch file.)

Answer (score 0):

you could always use Robocopy which supports wildcards, parsing sub directorys and multi threaded copying

```
Robocopy source destination /e /mt *.%FILETYPE%
```

MT only works on windows 7/2008 and higher